# How to get the features names for the data?

Tags: python, tree, tags, extract, rules

I used the following instructions with iris dataset that included with python environment

```
iris_data=load_iris()
feature_names = iris_data.feature_names 
k= tree.export_text(model.estimators_[i],feature_names)
```

I get the rules by this shape

```
"""\
|--- petal length (cm) <= 2.35
|   |--- class: 0.0
|--- petal length (cm) >  2.35
|   |--- petal width (cm) <= 1.65
|   |   |--- class: 1.0
|   |--- petal width (cm) >  1.65
|   |   |--- petal width (cm) <= 1.75
|   |   |   |--- sepal length (cm) <= 5.80
|   |   |   |   |--- class: 2.0"
```

but when I tried  to use the same instructions with outer dataset I get this error
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'feature_names'
also when I tried to get the features names by this instruction

```
fnm = list(dataset.columns.values.tolist())
k= tree.export_text(model.estimators_[i],fnm)
```

and use the same line to expert_text i get the following error*File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree_export.py", line 886, in export_textlen(feature_names)))
ValueError: feature_names must contain 3 elements, got 53*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [`sklearn.datasets.load_iris`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_iris.html) returns a `sklearn.utils.Bunch` object which has a `feature_names` attribute.

Your new dataset is a [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) object which has a `columns` attribute.

Comment: thank you ,I used data.columns and get the features names but when I execute the *tree.export_text(model.estimators_[i],feature_names)* the  rules generated as the following 
    |--- at1 <= 5.79
    |   |--- at2 <= 5.44
    |   |   |--- at2 <= 3.50
    |   |   |   |--- class <= 0.50
    |   |   |   |   |--- class: 0.0
    |   |   |   |--- class >  0.50
    |   |   |   |   |--- class: 1.0
I don't know why the class appear as a condition and has the value 0.5 despite  the values of the class are 0,1 and it is target .